# I am receiving this error when I try to send a file from react to django. (TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'file')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, api, django-rest-framework

Please help me solve this error.

When I try to get the data on api using file_serializer = FileSerializer(request.POST, request.FILES).
I receive error that name field is required even though I have passed it. I am not sure what more I can describe the error but any help would be appreciated.

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
import uuid

# Create your models here.
class File_Uploader(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    file = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=1000000000)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, db_index=True)
    size = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.file.name
```

Serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import File_Uploader
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = File_Uploader
        fields = ("file", "name", "size")
```

views.py

```
# from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.parsers import FileUploadParser, MultiPartParser
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import status

from .serializers import FileSerializer


class FileUploadView(APIView):
    permission_classes = []
    parser_class = (FileUploadParser,MultiPartParser,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      file_serializer = FileSerializer(data=request.data)
      if file_serializer.is_valid():
          file = file_serializer.data.get("file")
          name = file_serializer.data.get("name")
          size = file_serializer.data.get("size")
          queryset = FileSerializer(file=file, name=name, size=size)
          queryset.save()
          return Response(file_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
      else:
          return Response(file_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

React File Upload Code

```
submit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let file = e.target.files[0];
    let fileName = e.target.files[0].name;
    let fileSize = e.target.files[0].size;
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("file", file);
    data.append("name", fileName);
    data.append("size", fileSize);

    let url = "http://localhost:8000/api/files";
    axios.post(url, data, {
    }).then(res => {console.log(res.data);
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
  };
```

Error on React Side

```
POST http://localhost:8000/api/files
Status500
Internal Server Error
VersionHTTP/1.1
Transferred97.94 KB (97.68 KB size)
Referrer Policystrict-origin-when-cross-origin
Response From Django
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
  file_serializer = FileSerializer(data=request.data)
  if file_serializer.is_valid():
      file = file_serializer.data.get("file")
      name = file_serializer.data.get("name")
      size = file_serializer.data.get("size")
      queryset = FileSerializer(file=file, name=name, size=size) <-------
      queryset.save()
      return Response(file_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
  else:
      return Response(file_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Error on Django Side

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "J:\Lab\Programming\Django and React\JDrive\Backend\drenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "J:\Lab\Programming\Django and React\JDrive\Backend\drenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "J:\Lab\Programming\Django and React\JDrive\Backend\drenv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "J:\Lab\Programming\Django and React\JDrive\Backend\drenv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "J:\Lab\Programming\Django and React\JDrive\Backend\drenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "J:\Lab\Programming\Django and React\JDrive\Backend\drenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "J:\Lab\Programming\Django and React\JDrive\Backend\drenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "J:\Lab\Programming\Django and React\JDrive\Backend\drenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "J:\Lab\Programming\Django and React\JDrive\Backend\jdrive\api\views.py", line 23, in post
    queryset = FileSerializer(file=file, name=name, size=size)
  File "J:\Lab\Programming\Django and React\JDrive\Backend\drenv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "J:\Lab\Programming\Django and React\JDrive\Backend\drenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 115, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'file'
```

request captured in wireshark

```
POST /api/files HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------365966691829968063802789765478
Content-Length: 17448
Origin: http://localhost:3000
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
```

Comment: I think you missed header `content-type: 'multipart/form-data'`.

Comment: I tried this and it is still not working. Actually there is no need to specify this content-type because default POST request has this Content-type already so I did not put it.

Comment: Why are you decorating your serializer with `@csrf_exempt`? It does not make sense to use this decorator in this context

Comment: Ohh Sorry my bad

Comment: You don't need to create another `FileSerializer` instance, you already have a validated serializer. Just call `file_serializer.save()` after `if file_serializer.is_valid():`

Comment: Thanks brother this is working now. 